# How to set my CentOS domain name?

Tags: centos, domain, vps

I just bought a VPS and installed CentOS on it. Now I have a domain and I want it to point to my CentOS IP. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Voting to move to Webmasters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your DNS control panel and create an A record to point to your CentOS machine. How you do this will vary between providers, so I can't really be more specific than that.